# submitHandler() in jquery validate method taking time to execute and submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am using the jquery validate method to validate my form, I have written some code in submitHandler() method, However it taking time to execute. Please suggest me solution to overcome this issue.

```
$('#form').validate({
     submitHandler:function(form) {
           $('#loader').show();
           $('#btnsubmit').hide();
           $('#form').submit();
     }
});
```

This code taking time to hide the button and submit the form, Suggest me the solution to overcome this issue.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling `debug` option to know why is taking time to execute, and with another event do the `show hide` logic. For example:

```js
// show hide logic
$('#form #btnsubmit').click(function(e){
    $('#loader').show();
    $('#btnsubmit').hide();
})

$('#form').validate({
    // for debugging
    debug: true,
    submitHandler:function(form) {
       $('#form').submit();
    }
});
```